# 1px highlight top border in addition to full border?

Tags: html, css

I've tried googling this problem multiple times, but surprisingly don't find any results.

I'm trying to create a button that has a 1px dark border all the way around, but then also a 1px highlight border-top on the inside.

[image: Example button]
This image is a sample of what I'm trying to achieve. Is there any way to do this with just CSS3/HTML?

Current HTML:

```
<a href="register" title="Register Now" class="blue_button">Register Now</a>
```

Current CSS:

```
.blue_button {
    background-color: #019df6;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #019df6 0%, #027bc1 99%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#019df6), color-stop(99%,#027bc1));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #019df6 0%,#027bc1 99%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #019df6 0%,#027bc1 99%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #019df6 0%,#027bc1 99%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #019df6 0%,#027bc1 99%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#019df6', endColorstr='#027bc1',GradientType=0 );
    border:1px solid #0171b1;
    padding:10px 30px;
    font-weight:600;
    font-size:150%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: What's the exact HTML code and CSS code that you have been trying out?

Comment: @blamonet added to include. Currently only have the 1px outside border.

Comment: What your asking for is not the same across the board for all browsers.  You have a target browser you are focusing on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check out this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cEs4B/) You can use box-shadow to add the extra highlight top "border," and keep using border like you have it for the outer border. Without the "inset," the highlight will be on the outside of your existing border.

```
box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 1px white;
```

I used the following code on the jsFiddle, in addition to adding position and top rules:

```
box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 2px -2px white;
```